# Jar file not working properly?

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I made a classic hello world program in java called Hello.java:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

and I compiled it:`javac Hello.java`
then I made a manifest called manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: Hello
```

I then said `jar cfm myJar.jar manifest.txt Hello.class`
and indeed it made a jar file
but when I did `java -jar myJar.jar` it said no main manifest attribute. Thanks in *advance*.

Comment: The manifest File must be located in META-INF/ and the name must be MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

**jar -cvfm myJar.jar manifest.txt com.mysample.work.Hello.class**

v - verbose (optional)

Check your Hello class has the correct package

Answer (score 0):

You must modify META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and add this line Main-Class: com.mypackage.YourClass